# add new digits to a column of a text file in Python

Tags: python, text-files, edit

I am trying to edit some text files I have in order to add value to one of the columns. I would like to add two new digit to the second column of my files where are separated with space. The first column would ended on the 13 character, then there is two space and then add the new two digits and the other columns would remain without change.

I have written the following script but unfortunately it does work. I have be thankful if somebody could help me to find my mistake.

```
%********function************
def add_num(infile,outfile):
    output = ["%s  %s%s" %(item.strip()[:13] ,32,item.strip()[16:]) for item in infile]
    outfile.write("\n".join(output))
    outfile.close()
    return outfile
%*********************************
%**********main code for calling the function*******
import os, Add32
folder = 'E:/MLS_HFT/TEST/Stuttgart_2009_pointclouds/'
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
      infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
      if not os.path.isfile(infilename): continue
      base,extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
      infile= open(infilename, 'r')
      outfile = open(os.path.join(folder, '{}_32{}'.format(base,extension)),'w')
      add32.add_num(infile,outfile)
```

and this is a sample of a data:

```
 399299.855212  512682.330  5403021.950  303.471  64    1  1  2        75
 399299.855212  512681.470  5403020.790  302.685  1     1  2  2        75
 399299.855222  512682.360  5403021.970  303.526  79    1  1  2        76
```

Comment: what do you mean "it doesnt work"? is there an error?  what are you getting and what should you be getting?

Comment: well, I would receive an empty outputs.

Comment: so nothing is written to outfile? it does not (and should not) print anything. how are you calling it?

Comment: yes, nothing is written

Comment: then you are calling your function wrong ... there is nothing wrong with the function

Comment: @Joran Beasley: I have edited the code including the main code as well, would you please have a look at it, in case there is a problem in calling?

Comment: why dont you try printing your `outfile_filename` before the open call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('infile.txt', 'rb') as infile, open('outfile.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(line[:15] + '32' + line[15:] for line in infile)
```

Comment: :Thank you for your help. I have tried your code and it works nicely, but just there is one problem which is space after 32. I expect that 32 should be part of the second column not a new column. would u plz edit it in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.split`:

```
col = 2
#just pass filenames to your function and use `with` statement for handling files.
with open(infile) as f, open(outfile, 'w') as out:
    for line in f:
        spl = line.split(None, col)
        spl[col -1] = '32' + spl[col -1]
        out.write(" ".join(spl))
...         
399299.855212 32512682.330 5403021.950  303.471  64    1  1  2        75

399299.855212 32512681.470 5403020.790  302.685  1     1  2  2        75

399299.855222 32512682.360 5403021.970  303.526  79    1  1  2        76
```

Working version of your code:

```
def add_num(infile,outfile):
   with open(infile) as f, open(outfile, 'w') as out:
      output = ["%s  %s%s\n" %(item.strip()[:13] ,32,item.strip()[16:]) for item in f]
      out.writelines(output)

outfile = os.path.join(folder, '{}_32{}'.format(base,extension))
add_num(infilename,outfile)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. so may I ask in the above code where should I define my output file?

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary: Thank you for your guidance. I tired your code but still no output :(

Comment: @user2355306 You must be running it incorrectly, I've added another example similar to your code.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary : after running the above I receive an error on ther line 'add_num(infilename,outfile)'. What do you think it refers to?

Comment: @user2355306 python version?

Comment: @user2355306 then it should work fine, there are no errors. You're not running it properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
def add_num(infile,outfile):
    output = ["%s  %s%s" %(item.strip()[:13] ,32,item.strip()[16:]) for item in infile]
    outfile.write("\n".join(output))
    outfile.close()
    return outfile

add_num(open("infile.data"),open("outfile.data","w"))
```

then look at outfile.data ... nothing wrong with your function probably how you are calling it

Comment: yeah I just wanted to do a quick example that shows it works fine ... there are some other examples on using with ;)

Comment: I have edited the code including the main code as well, would you please have a look at it, in case there is a problem in calling?

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice notation to insert characters, for example

```
myString = myString[:15] + "  12" + myString[15:]
```

will insert 4 characters at position 15

the first slice `myString[:15]` will get a substring from the beginning to the 15th position

the second slice `myString[15:]` will get a substring from the 15th position to the end

you can concatenate that by adding in your characters to the middle